# Show Symfony queries from vendors on Profiler

Tags: symfony, debugging, profiler, vendor

I have a symfony project with some services in a private vendor where I execute some db queries, but profiler is not showing this queries on the toolbar, is that a known issue or I'm doing something wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: The profiler db tab show ALL queries for the process. Are you sure that your vendor code is run ?

Comment: Yes @Mcsky, the code is running that's why I don't understant what's happening.